# Pass own made Windows Credentials to SQL Server using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, security, jdbc

I'm trying to write a program that connects to SQL Server at work, which I have done and works perfectly. However, this program only works on the desktop at my workplace because it is connected to the SQL Server that I wanted it connect local. This means if I were to work on this program at home, I won't be able to do anything as it can't connect to it.

What I've found out is that the server uses windows auth to authenticate the users who connects to SQL Server. From what I found out is that windows authentication on SQL Server gets the credentials for the security. So I was wondering is there a way where I can get the credentials using Java, then pass that to SQL Server using JDBC to login to the database?? Or is this not really realistic to do? If so, is there any way around this?

Thanks

Comment: No you can't do that. You need to use "SQL Server Authentication" instead (which requires re-configuring your SQL Server instance)

Answer (score 0):

When you install MS SQL Server you are asked about the type of authentication that you want.

I personally cannot think of a Scenario where pure "Windows Authentication" makes sense. I always choose "Mixed Mode" as with pure Windows Authentication to much can go wrong. (Server-Admin gets fired, Company merges with another AD-Domain, spontaneous SID-corruptions etc...)

That said, you'll Need to [Change Authentication Mode to Mixed Mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx).